# Bloomberg Libor Rates

Tags: bloomberg, excel

I load swap rates data from Bloomberg in excel using the command

```
=BDH(Ticker,"Px Last",Start_Date,End_Date,"Dts",FALSE)
```

The tickers I use are "USSW1 Curncy", "EUSA1 Curncy", "BPSW1 Curncy", etc...

First of all, I would like to know what this "Curncy" keyword stand for. Then as I am also interested in LIBOR rates, I would like to know if I have to add this "Curncy" keyword to "US0001W", "US0001M" as well.

Please note that I don't have a direct access to Bloomberg, so I need firstly to have a proper template. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For Swaps it's correct to use the "**Curncy**" keyword, as for Futures it's the "**Comdty**" keyword.

For example: **USSW1 Curncy**   0,4455 - 0,4475 - 0,4495

However, for Money Market Rates such as Libor, you want to use "**Index**".

For example:

**US00O/N Index**   PX_LAST - 0,1164

**US0006M Index**   PX_LAST - 0,3623

*Hope this was helpfull.*

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the OP mentioned that he/she does not have direct access to the Bloomberg, so even though this doesn't directly answer the question I want to add that LIBOR is downloadable from the St. Louis Federal Reserve system called "FRED" at http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/release?rid=253 although it is delayed by a few  business days.  Since the LIBOR rigging scandal, oversight of the LIBOR has been turned over to the ICE exchange and they charge a considerable sum for "real-time" LIBOR.